# Rules for int[] array initialization from initializer list

Tags: c++, c++17

I would appreciate pointers to the int array initialization list in the C++ standard, I found an inconsistency between clang and gcc (c++ 17), see below and in compiler explorer.

https://godbolt.org/z/3vMfTv8Ts

Questions:
Why can v1 be initialized with a initializer list, but we can't initialize a temporary to pass it to Test2?
Why clang and gcc have different behavior when the function param is a reference to the int array?

Note: clang C++20 compiles the Test1 call.

I would appreciate the pointer to the C++ standard where these rules are described.

```
#include <iostream>

int Test1(const int (&a)[]) {
    return a[0];
}

int Test2(const int a[]) {
    return a[0];
}

int main() {
    const int v1[] = { 1,2,3 };

    std::cout << Test2(v1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Test2({ 1,2,3 }) << std::endl; // Does not compile in clang/gcc
    std::cout << Test1({ 1,2,3 }) << std::endl; // Does not compile in clang
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int Test2(const int[])` is literally the same as `int Test2(const int*)`. `template<int N> int Test1(const int (&a)[N])` will work.

Comment: This appears to me to be more about temporaries, type conversion and parameter passing than array initialization.